# Restriction rule for administrator certification spring 22

Tags: restrictionrules, restriction

I am trying to maintain my administrator certification [spring 22](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/administrator-certification-maintenance-spring-22/maintain-your-administrator-certification-for-spring22) and in the challenge section I have created a restriction rule as per the instructions, but I can't seem to activate the rule. It gives the following error

> You reached the active restriction rule limit. To make this restriction rule active, first delete or deactivate one.

I only have one restriction rule on task object which I created as part the challenge in my trailhead org. I have [turned off Salesforce Classic for your org](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lex_turn_off_classic.htm&language=en_US&type=5) to rule out that issue possiblity as well but to no avail.

Comment: Hi, did you check this point "only one restriction rule at most can have the User Criteria field evaluate to true for a given user." for an object

Comment: Yea, as mentioned I only have one restriction rule and that has user criteria. Thats the only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly know the reason but creating a **new playground** org and completing the challenge there did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I was facing the same issue. In dev orgs, if you look at the limit allowed, it says 0 out of 0 active rules. This implies that you cannot create any restriction rules.

So I created a playground org for this and the limit was 0 out of 2 active rules which allowed me to create an active rule and complete the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps older playgrounds did not upgrade to Spring '23 and so the limit for them is zero. That could be why a new playground solves this issue.